# Meteor template helper not working after using iron router

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, meteor, meteor-helper

I'm new to Meteor and I just installed iron router to my project. I have this inside my **application.js** file:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

  Template.nav.helpers({
    isMobile: function(){
      if(isMobile.tablet) {
        return false;
      } else if(isMobile.phone) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  });

}
```

The `isMobile` helper will be used inside my `nav` template like this:

```
<template name="nav">
...
  {{#if isMobile}}
    {{> mobile_nav}}
  {{else}}
    {{> desktop_nav}}
  {{/if}}          
...
</template>
```

What I'm doing here is, I'm loading 2 different sets of navigation. If the user is using desktop or tablet, I'm going to show `desktop_nav` template and when the user is using phone, I'm going to show `mobile_nav`.

[This is the jQuery plugin](https://github.com/kaimallea/isMobile) that I use inside the `isMobile` template helper.

Inside my **application.html** file, I have this:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Example</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>

<template name="main">
    {{> nav}}   
        {{> yield}}
    {{> footer}}
</template>
```

And this is my **router.js** file:

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'main'
});

Router.route('/', 'home');

Router.route('/about', 'about');
```

My problem right now is, the `isMobile` template helper doesn't work. The `nav` template is loaded but the `if else` block is not working.

It was working fine before I start using iron router.

What am I missing here?

Note, this is my project structure tree:

```
├── application.css.scss
├── application.html
├── application.js
├── client
│   ├── javascripts
│   │   ├── isMobile.min.js
│   │   └── router.js
│   ├── stylesheets
│   │   └── ...
│   └── views
│       ├── about.html
│       ├── home.html
│       ├── home.js
│       └── layouts
│           ├── desktop_nav.html
│           ├── footer.html
│           ├── mobile_nav.html
│           └── nav.html
└── public
    ├── fonts
    │   └── ...
    └── images
        └── ...
```

Comment: Place a console.log(isMobile) as the first line in your isMobile helper function. If it is not "undefined", then the isMobile jQuery plugin works. I tried, it should work so my guess is something else is wrong. To get specific answer, need your sample project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. It was due I'm not initializing the foundation. After I add it, my menu works fine:

```
Template.desktop_nav.onRendered(function(){
    $(document).foundation();
});

Template.mobile_nav.onRendered(function(){
    $(document).foundation();
});
```

Another important thing to keep in mind is, `$(this).foundation();` doesn't work. Only `$(document).foundation();` works. I've no idea what's the differences between `$(this)` and `$(document)` in this context.

Thank Villemh and 3thanZ for the help. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You should render the templates into your layout. Here is a good tutorial that can help you.

http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#rendering-templates-into-regions-with-javascript

So something like this:

```
Router.route('/', function () {
  this.render('main');
});
```

Also check the console in the browser, it might have some errors from Iron Router

Comment: It's not working for me. No errors found inside the JS console.

Comment: thats strange.. if you can, maybe you can provide some code repo, it would be easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the `isMobile` jQuery plugin is interfering with your `isMobile` helper function? Did you try renaming your `isMobile` helper function to something else? And perhaps do a `console.log(isMobile.tablet, isMobile.phone)` from your helper function to make sure that it is being called?